# How do i make my progress bar accessible for people using screen readers?

Tags: progress-bar, accessibility

I have a progress bar on my website which indicates to the user, visually, at what point in the process they are at. There are 3 steps and they need to complete each step, in order, to finish.

There is a header above the progress bar which says 
Enter details (Step1 of 3) or Confirm details (Step 2 of 3) or  Renewal complete (Step 3 of 3)

Say you're on the first step, the screen reader reads out the header and then the progress bar text, and then the following header, like so:

Enter details (Step1 of 3) 
Enter details   Confirm details   Renewal complete 
Enter your details 
All fileds marked with (*) are required

I don't feel that the progress bar helps to indicate, to the user of a screen reader, at what point in the process they are currently at and how much more they need to do (which is the whole purpose of the progress bar!)
Do people think that adding text to the progress bar and then hiding it visually would be a good thing to do?
I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
Enter details <span class="hidden">Active</span> Confirm details<span class="hidden">Incomplete</span> Renewal complete<span class="hidden">Incomplete</span>
```

And then adding in the css

```
.hidden { text-indent:-3000px; 
or
  font-size:0px; }
```

Or do you think that the first header is all the people using screen readers need to hear and the addition of the progress bar is just confusing and i should hide it from them? In which case, how do i do that?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1):

Use [WAI-ARIA](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria) attributes. [Progressbar role](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#progressbar) seems to be just what you need. Screen readers can then use those attributes to accurately represent your intent.

Comment: This is somewhat tricky; the ARIA progressbar role is usually used against desktop-style progress bars, the sort you see in Windows file copy dialogs, that fill up as the operation completes (and indicates system progress - not user's progress). What the OP is describing is a bit different; it's more like a breadcrumb bar, describing progress made and progress yet to be made - these are fairly common on sites where you carry out a transaction such as purchasing a book or booking a flight. Visually they don't look at all like progress bars, so using that role might confuse a user...

Comment: Part of the problem here is that ARIA's vocabulary is based on desktop idioms, so it doesn't have any role that's a perfect fit for this idiom, which is somewhat specific to HTML/web. You might be able to get the progressbar role to work here; putting it on a div that surrounds the entire thing; and using the aria-valuetext attribute to indicate the current item. Would need to test it with a couple of screenreaders to see how well it works - notably whether they also read out the textual content within the bar in addition to the bar itself.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but did anyone get this ever to work. I tried it but no luck on my end.